# Mapping two domain classes in Grails

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, grails-domain-class

I have two tables in our database that need mapped. The first is a **Student** table. It looks something like this:

```
id
first_name
last_name
major_code_1
major_code_2
```

And the **Major** table is like this:

```
id
description
```

I need to map the major codes of the student, where `major_code_1` and `major_code_2` point to an `id` in the Major table. How could I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple model which maps to your schema:

```
class Student {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Major firstMajor
    Major secondMajor

    static mapping = {
        table 'Student'
        firstMajor column: 'major_code_1'
        secondMajor column: 'major_code_2'
    }
}

class Major {
    String description

    static mapping = {
        table 'Major'
    }
}
```

I've left out all `belongsTo` and other ownership fields as you didn't specify cascade behavior in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code can look like (with one-to-many relations: Major can have many Students):

```
class Student{

    Long id 
    String first_name
    String last_name

    static belongsTo = [
            major_code_1: Major
            , major_code_2: Major
    ]

    static mapping = {
        table 'Student'
    }

}


class Major{

    Long id 
    String description

    static hasMany = [
        student_1: Student
        , student_2: Student
    ]

    static mappedBy = [
            student_1: 'major_code_1'
            , student_2: 'major_code_2'
    ]

    static mapping = {
        table 'Major'
    }

}
```

But could you please explain me the idea of this two tables. Because it looks like recursive relationship many to many between Major Entity which is called Student. I wonder if you shouldn't have student_code_1 and student_code_2 in the Major table.

-------------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------------------

With many-to-one relation (Many Students have the same Major)

```
class Student{

    Long id 
    String first_name
    String last_name

    Major major_code_1
    Major major_code_2

    static mapping = {
        table 'Student'
    }

}


class Major{

    Long id 
    String description

    static belongsTo = [
        student_1: Student
        , student_2: Student
    ]

    static mappedBy = [
            student_1: 'major_code_1'
            , student_2: 'major_code_2'
    ]

    static mapping = {
        table 'Major'
    }

}
```

Comment: Basically the Student object can have two majors...major1, major2. In the database, the the major_code_1 and major_code_2 in the student able is just a code that points to the Major table. From there you can get the major description (Computer Information Science, Economics, etc.)

Being a university, this is a legacy database so if it doesn't map well to Grails domain classes then well, that's why.

Comment: Now I understand. So code from my answer should work fine. You can only add a constraint is Student class to avoid having two the same majors for one student.

Comment: Would this need to change a bit if the Student is on the owning side?

Comment: I've added solution with many-to-one relation. So now the Student is on the owning side.

Comment: The first approach if you drop a major all your students will be gone and with the second approach if you drop a Student the corresponding major will be gone.