# How would I map this existing DB in Grails?

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping

We have an existing Oracle database and I would like to map it in Grails 2.2.3 so I can use it with GORM. I have an Authorization table that has primary keys in it for several entities such as Fund, Organization, Account, etc. Here is what the table looks like:

```
Table: PHONE_AUTH

ID             NOT NULL     NUMBER
AUTH_CODE                   VARCHAR2
FUND                        VARCHAR2
ORGANIZATION                VARCHAR2
ACCOUNT                     VARCHAR2
```

The Fund, Organization, and Account columns are just primary keys that map to records in other tables (the Fund table, the Account table, etc.) How would I map this in Grails? Will I need to use `static embedded = ['fund', 'organization', 'account']`? Or use `mappedBy` in some way? Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem with [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17678991/2051952)? Moreover, you have a simple one-to-one relationship you can use `static hasOne` as shown [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html).

Comment: Are you also mapping the Fund, Org, and Account tables?

Comment: @JamesKleeh Yes, the Fund, Org, and Account tables are also Grails domain objects in this case.

Answer (score 2):

So something like this

```
class PhoneAuth {

    String authCode
    Fund fund
    Organization organization
    Account account

    static mapping = {
        table 'phone_auth'
        version false
        fund column: 'fund'
        organization column: 'organization'
        account column: 'account'
    }
}
```